# How to convert this curl command to c#?

Tags: c#, azure, curl, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops-rest-api

curl -x http://ip:port -key mykey.key -cert mycert.cert https://url -h "exampleheader:examplevalue"

Comment: Please explain in detail. What did you mean by _convert command to C#_?

Comment: @HosseinGolshani Our clients give an API service to get a token. This API request needs our SSL client certificate and privateKey when we call it. This request is like below **curl -x ProxyIP:Port -v --key MyPrivateKey.key --cert MyCertificate.crt clientrequestURL -H "Headerkey:HeaderKeyValue"** This is our Curl request. I need this request this query in c#. I try it lot of ways but its getting 401 access denied error every time. Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

### UPDATE Code

```
// Use this if you are in a web context
// var certificatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
//                  "your_client_certificate_path"),

// Use this in a non web context. 
// certificatePath should be the same value as the parameter you are using 
// in your command line
//  -cert mycert.cert   <------ This one
var certificatePath = "your_physical_path_file_to_mycert.cert";

// Certificate from file 
var _clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
                          certificatePath,
                          "your_client_certificate_key");

// Web handler
var handler = new System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(_clientCertificate);

// Http Client
var _httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Header Key", "Header Value");

// Requests
_httpClient.GetAsync("your_request_URI");
```

Comment: Thanks Alfredo. But its not working. I have getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error at this line **var _clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
                      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                          "your_client_certificate_path"), 
                      "your_client_certificate_key");**

Comment: **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath( "your_client_certificate_path")** is for a web context, if you are not in an Asp. NET app it will not work. In wich context are you? The idea is for you to get the physical path of your file

Comment: I am creating .net window app for Geting SAS token.

Comment: The **X509Certificate2** constructor takes two parameter, the first one is the fisical path for your certificate. It is just a string, e.g. something like ***"C:\MyCertificates\mycert.cert"***, you should provide the path to your file. Exactly what error are you getting? **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** is being thrown because you are using  **ystem.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath** and **System.Web.HttpContext.Current** is **null** because you are not in a web context, but that line was just placed as an example to obtain the physical path of the cert file.

Comment: "your_client_certificate_key" what its mean? Private key or cert password? if its mean Private key the what I should given? Privatekey file path or privatekey file content string.